# Pandas: join two time series data based on multicolumn index

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes. First `df_1` one is with data states with following format:

```
session_id | user_id | timestamp | state1 | state2
```

And the second one is with another dataframe `df_2` states with format:

```
session_id | user_id | timestamp | state3 | state4
```

I want to join them into final dataframe with following structure:

```
session_id | user_id | timestamp | state1 | state2 | state3 | state4
```

I want to keep rows from both  frames not just overlaying. Something like this:

```
 session_id  user_id  timestamp  state1  state2  state3  state4 
0         1        1      14:00       1       1       0       1    
1         1        2      14:00     NAN     NAN       0       1
2         1        3      14:00       1       0     NAN     NAN
```

Basically I think it should be a `outer join`. So I studied documentation and come up with this:

```
df_1.set_index(['session_id', 'user_id', 'timestamp']).join(
   df_2.set_index(['session_id', 'user_id', 'timestamp']), how="outer")
```

But it is not working right way. It just puts dataframes one under another. What should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply perform an outer merge, as below.

By default, `pd.merge` works on the intersection of columns.

**Setup**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'session_id': [1, 1],
                    'state1': ['1', '1'],
                    'state2': ['1', '0'],
                    'timestamp': ['14:00', '14:00'],
                    'user_id': [1, 3]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'session_id': [1],
                    'state3': ['0'],
                    'state4': ['1'],
                    'timestamp': ['14:00'],
                    'user_id': [2]})
```

**Solution**

```
res = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer')
```

**Result**

```
   session_id  user_id timestamp state1 state2 state3 state4
0           1        1     14:00      1      1    NaN    NaN
1           1        3     14:00      1      0    NaN    NaN
2           1        2     14:00    NaN    NaN      0      1
```